# Sorting (n x 2) array based on the first column using STL algorithm's sort ( ) function

Tags: c++, sorting, stl, multidimensional-array, stl-algorithm

I want to sort a (nx2) array based on its first column using the sort( ) function in the algorithm library in C++. I couldn't figure out the way to use the **3rd parameter** concerning the **custom function in the sort() function**.
The code below is not compiling.

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n,k,i,j,missile[100000][2];
    scanf("%d",&n);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        scanf("%d %d",&missile[i][0], &missile[i][1]);
    }

    bool sortFunc( int *missile[i][0], int *missile[j][0])
    {
        return missile[i][0]<missile[j][0];
    }

    sort(missile,missile+n,sortFunc);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        printf("%d %d\n",missile[i][0],missile[i][1]);
    }


    return 0;
}
```

From whatever I understood I changed my code to

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  int n;
  scanf("%d",&n);
  vector< pair<int,int> > missile(n);
  for(auto p:missile)
     scanf("%d %d",&(p.first),&(p.second));

  sort(begin(missile),end(missile),less) //Using the default comparator for pair

  for(auto p:missile)
    printf("%d %d\n",p.first,p.second);
  return 0;
}
```

Still getting many compiling errors

```
    hackerrank_missile.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
    hackerrank_missile.cpp:12: error: a function-definition is not allowed here before ‘:’ token
    hackerrank_missile.cpp:15: error: ‘begin’ was not declared in this scope
    hackerrank_missile.cpp:15: error: ‘end’ was not declared in this scope
    hackerrank_missile.cpp:15: error: missing template arguments before ‘)’ token
    hackerrank_missile.cpp:17: error: expected `;' before ‘for’
    hackerrank_missile.cpp:17: error: expected primary-expression before ‘for’
    hackerrank_missile.cpp:17: error: expected `)' before ‘for’
    hackerrank_missile.cpp:17: error: a function-definition is not allowed here before ‘:’ token
    hackerrank_missile.cpp:19: error: expected primary-expression before ‘return’
    hackerrank_missile.cpp:19: error: expected `;' before ‘return’
    hackerrank_missile.cpp:19: error: expected primary-expression before ‘return’
    hackerrank_missile.cpp:19: error: expected `)' before ‘return’
```

Comment: You need to read more about [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort), especially the comparison function and its arguments.

Comment: Also, you can't use nested functions. And why are you using C functions (like `scanf` and `printf`) instead of the standard C++ I/O functions?

Comment: I would also recommend you using a [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) of [`std::pair`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair) for your collection instead.

Comment: You could also use a struct with 2 variables inside it. Then overload '<' and you are done.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I am trying to solve for a competition and it is mentioned to use STD input and output and not cin and cout.
I understand that vector and pair would be 'nicer' but array should also work just fine.

Comment: In C++, the standard input/output *is* `std::cin` and `std::cout`.

Comment: Got your point. But those are ways of polishing the code. I want to know the fundamental mistake in the above code since I was not able to understand overloading in the sort().

Comment: *The code below is not working.* I bet it's **not compiling** either. So you first should fix that.

Comment: To press `std::sort` into service here, it wouldn't be enough to craft a custom comparison predicate - you would also need a custom iterator class that wraps a pair of ints. You can't treat your array as a sequence of elements of type int[2], because int[2] is not copyable or assignable. This is why it would be much easier to work with an array (or vector) of pair<int, int>, or a user-defined structure with two int members, or even a user-defined structure with a single int[2] member.

Comment: It is highly likely if you used `std::pair<>` for your data element rather than a row from a 2D array the default comparator of `std::less<std::pair<T,T>>` will do precisely what you want, so if this is for some competition you're making it harder for yourself doing it another way.

Answer (score 0):

This code at least compiles (using c++11, except for C-style IO) via
`clang++ test.cc -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -Weverything -Wno-c++98-compat`.
If it does what you want, I don't know.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
  std::size_t n;
  std::scanf("%ld",&n);
  std::vector<std::pair<int,int>> missile(n);
  for(auto&p:missile)
    std::scanf("%d %d",&(p.first),&(p.second));
  std::sort(std::begin(missile),std::end(missile),[](std::pair<int,int> const&i,
                                                     std::pair<int,int> const&j)
      { return i.first < j.first; });
  for(auto p:missile)
    std::printf("%d %d\n",p.first,p.second);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: It is not compiling on my system. Why have you once used p and the other time &p with 'auto'

Comment: @Shivendra Did you specify `-std=c++11` as compiler option? `auto&p` ensures that the state of `p` can be altered (reading it in), while `auto p` will not allow that (it will read into a temporary but not into the `vector<>`).